# Gitlab pipeline checkout access

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying pipelines in git lab community edition.

For what I can understand, from gitlab, the code and pipelines live in the same git repository.

In my scenario the pipelines are responsibility of devops team and code from develop team.

How, in git lab, is possible to prevent developers of changing the pipeline?
I understand it's possible to add devops team as maintainer to review pull requests, but this will create a dependency of devops teams in every change.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab is not really designed for the scenario you describe. The general idea is that developers look after the CI configuration themselves.

You could try using the [includes feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#includefile) to store the bulk of the CI configuration in a separate repository.

In the application repository you would have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that pulls the CI configuration in from another repository using include-project:

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-ciproject'
    ref: master
    file: '/ci/.gitlab-ci-myappproject.yml'
```

Then in the my-group/my-ciproject repository you would have a file `.gitlab-ci-myappproject.yml` that contains the GitLab CI jobs configuration.

```
build:
  script:
    - dobuild
```

Only the DevOps team would have access to the my-group/my-ciproject repository so developers can't edit the CI config (although could mess with the .gitlab-ci.yml` file in the app repository).

Alternatively you could protect the master branch and have all changes approved before merging to master. Then developers would not be able to make changes to the CI without an approval.